# What happens if I exceed my database size allowance on Heroku?

Tags: database, heroku, hosting

I'm currently testing a web app on Heroku and using their free 5MB shared database tier, and very nice it is too.

However, there is a possibility some of the test data I generate may end up putting the app over the 5MB limit.

**What happens if I do exceed this limit?**

I don't think I've yet given Heroku my billing information so presumably they won't charge me. Will I suddenly get error messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it it is a soft limit, and they'll email you if you start taking the mickey